# Do I need to have CPU throttling turned off just to build ATLAS or all the time?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, atlas

I am installing NumPy on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and it the install first requires that I install ATLAS. For this I am told I need to disable CPU throttling. My question is do I just need to disable it for the build or all the time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to turn it off during the installation phase. It interferes with the performance tests and measurements during the install phase.

The related [section](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node5.html) in the installation guide states:

> CPU throttling makes pretty much all timings completely random, and so any ATLAS install will be junk. Therefore, before installing ATLAS, turn off CPU throttling.